# Make TabView background fill whole tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Here is where I am right now: [screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub0mx.jpg).

Ignoring the tab indicator (which I will figure out later) the problem I'm having is the background I set for the selected tab seems to only be filling the text of the tab.

I would like for the tab selected background to fill the selected tab, and not just the text.

Here's what I've done so far:

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="LoginActionBar"
        parent="@style/MyActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/LoginActionBarTabs</item>

    </style>

    <style name="LoginActionBarTabs"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/login_actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**res/drawable/login_actionbar_tab_indicator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="false"
          android:drawable="@color/loginTab"  />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@color/loginTabSelected" />
</selector>
```

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="loginTabSelected">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="loginTab">#999999</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put the `TextView` as `matchparent` for height and width and use your selector for its background.